# Convert nvarchar to bigint from SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I want to copy `sqi_main` from `middleman24` to `sqi_test` in `sqitable`.

- `sqi_test` type is `bigint`
- `sqi_main` type is `nvarchar(20)`

I use this command in SQL Server 2014:

```
INSERT INTO sqitable(sqi_test) 
    SELECT sqi_main  
    FROM Middleman24
```

`sqi_main` content is

```
2
3
1
-5
30
-1
50
```

But I get this error:

> Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint.

I have tried other solutions like

```
INSERT INTO sqitable(sqi_test) 
    SELECT sqi_main  
    FROM Middleman24 
    WHERE ISNUMERIC(sqi) = 1 
      AND sqi <> ''
```

But again I get the same error.

Comment: `ISNUMERIC` is very error-prone. For example: `$, +, -` all evaluate to `1`.

Comment: @HoneyBadger - it's not error-prone, it just answers a question nobody wants to ask "can this string be converted to *any* of the numeric data types (I don't care which one(s))?"

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, you're right, I'll choose my words more carefully :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have SOME data somewhere that can't be converted to a `bigint`, and as one of the commenters mentioned, `ISNUMERIC` isn't a perfect solution.

Since you're using SQL 2014, use the `TRY_CONVERT()` function (`TRY_PARSE()` can also be used).  Google or search MSDN for all the details.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I try TRY_CONVERT() and TRY_PARSE(). They fixed error.

Comment: I Choose TRY_Convert() for my application, because it works well with nvarchar types too.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use CAST if data is clean:

```
SELECT CAST(sqi_main as bigint) FROM Middleman24;
```

Otherwise, use [TRY_PARSE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213126(v=sql.120).aspx):

```
SELECT TRY_PARSE(sqi_main as bigint) FROM Middleman24;
```

Comment: I use cast() before but the error not fixed. but Try_Parse() is Solution and fixed the error. 
Thanks.

Comment: Cast works well with clean data. Try parse first check your data and return null if it cannot parse it. It doesn't return an error.